# Run command line for each file in folder - quotation mark issue (I think)

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run a run the following command line for each specific file type (as example for each .txt file) in the current directory:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\some program\someprogram.exe" "file.txt" "file.txt.mod" -someparameter
```

When I run this exact command from an open Windows command prompt (including all the quotation marks), it works.
But when I run it through this VB, it does nothing/closes right away.

What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling it has to do with the quotes, but my head can't sort it out.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
objStartFolder = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles 
    strFileName = objFile.Name
    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "txt" Then
        RunCommand()
    End If
Next

Sub RunCommand
    Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    oShell.run "cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\some program\someprogram.exe"" """ & objFile.Path & """ """ & objFile.Path & ".mod"" -someparameter"
    Set oShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should

- Reduce risk of failures

by

1. using "Option Explicit"
2. avoiding clever "roll your own" hacks by using standard methods (.GetParentFolderName) instead
3. using type prefixes correctly (objStartFolder)
4. avoiding variables just used once (objFolder, colFiles)
5. not using globals to pass parameters into Subs/Functions (objFile)
6. avoiding (unnecessary) stress (.Run without wait, new WScript.Shell for each file, "cmd" instead of "%comspec%")
7. using cscript in a 'dos box' instead of double click/wscript

and

- check your assumptions

by

1. diagnostic output (.Echo objFile.Name immediately before calling RunCommand, use a variable to store and .Echo the command send to .Run)
2. Check return values of functions that provide diagnostics (.Run)
3. sanity checks like:

(just to tame the formatter)

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetExtensionName("A.TXT")
>>
TXT
```

Comment: Using `cmd /k` instead of `cmd /c` might help, too. Also, I'd recommend testing the procedure on a single file first before running it in a loop.